# Handling multilevel menus in React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm projecting Photoshop-like app that looks like this:

```
[ Sidebar ] [ Sub-Sidebar ] [ Main Application ]
```

There are about 10 positions in the sidebar and on click every single one reloads Sub-Sidebar but nothing else (especially not Main Application). Every Sub-Sidebar has different, sometimes massive options and I don't know what's the right approach here.

I guess I want to push every click through Redux, but how do I load Sub-Sidebar for every case then?

I was thinking about returning proper components in Sidebar's reducer, but I don't know if it is a good/valid pattern? I could always load all the Sub-sidebars and toggle through them jQuery-like, but I don't want to load them all at once as some of them hold tens of textures etc.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)?

Each of `Sidebar` elements could be `Link`s which load a specific path in the application.

```
<Link to="/sub/subA" > SubA </Link>
```

The `Sub - SideBar` component can define `Route`s which would change the `Sub-Sidebar` as per the route to be rendered.

```
<Route path="/sub/subA" component={SubMenuA}/>
```

The different `Sub-SideBar` s can themselves be created using `Link`s which would then be handled by the `MainApplication` section as needed.

Comment: But won't react-router rerender everything on the page instead of just one simple sidebar?